# How to prove that this set is basis of closed sets of some topology ( called Zariski Topology ) on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology

The following question was asked in my topology quiz and I am unable to solve it. So, I am asking for help here.

> Question:  Let n$\in \mathbb{N}$ , and let P denote the collection of all polynomials in n variables. For p$\in P$ , let Z(p)= {$(x_1, x_2, ...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: p((x_1,x_2, ... ,x_n))=0$}. Show that {$Z(p): p\in P$}  is basis for the closed sets of some topology (called Zariski Topology ) on $\mathbb{R}^n$} .

The problem is that in the quiz it was not mentioned what is zariski topology and also it was not taught in the class. So, I am not able to understand what it's open sets, closed sets will be.

Also, I didn't googled for zariski topology because in question it is not given what is zariski topology which means that it has to be solved without using the definition of zariski topology(I think).

So, Can you please help me with this?

Comment: The fact that is called Zariski topology is just for informational purposes. An interesting fact, as it were, to illustrate that is well-known and not a random exercise. Focus on the task: what are the properties that you have to check that $\{Z(p): p \in P\}$ is a base of closed sets for some topology at all? You're *given* the definition, you don't have to do or know aything about it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Ok,I am unable to show how can I prove the complement to be open. Can you please prove that ?

Comment: what are the conditions to define a base for closed sets (without having a topology yet)?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Base_for_the_closed_sets) e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks!I have done it.